# Formatting a nested table in HTML

Tags: css, html, web

I'm having a hard time doing this assignment. It's a simple HTML coding assignment but I'm having problems formatting my table to look like what's asked. I've tried different types of breaks etc, but it just won't work in the way the instructor wants it.

Here's my table:

[image: This is my table]

And here's the one my instructor wants:

[image: This is what the instructor wants]

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <table border="border">
    <tr>
      <th>Header Column 1</th>
      <th>Header Column 2</th>
      <th>Header Column 3</th>
      <th>Header Column 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 - Item 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 - Item 2</td>
      <td><b>Row 2:Nested table 1</b>
        <table border="border">
          <tr>
            <th>Row 1 Header</th>
            <td>item</td>
            <tr>
              <th>Row 2 Header</th>
              <td>item</td>
              <tr>
                <th>Row 2 Header</th>
                <td>item</td>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>Row 2 - Item 4
        <br>A second line</td>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 3 - Item 1</td>
        <td>Row 3 - Item 2</td>
        <td>
          <br>
        </td>
        <td>Row 3 - Item 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 4 - Item 1</td>
        <td>Row 4 - Item 2</td>
        <td>Row 4 - Item 3</td>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the concept `rowspan` for particular `<td>`

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border = "border">
 <tr>
  <th>Header Column 1</th>
  <th>Header Column 2</th>
  <th>Header Column 3</th>
  <th>Header Column 4</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Row 2 - Item 1</td>
   <td>Row 2 - Item 2</td>
   <td rowspan=2><b>Row 2:Nested table 1</b>
      <table border = "border">
         <tr><th>Row 1 Header</th><td>item</td>
         <tr><th>Row 2 Header</th><td>item</td>
         <tr><th>Row 2 Header</th><td>item</td>
       </table>
       </td>
   <td>Row 2 - Item 4<br>A second line</td>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3 - Item 1</td>
    <td>Row 3 - Item 2</td>
    <td rowspan=2>Row 3 - Item 3</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 4 - Item 1</td>
    <td>Row 4 - Item 2</td>
    <td>Row 4 - Item 3</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border = "border">
 <tr>
  <th>Header Column 1</th>
  <th>Header Column 2</th>
  <th>Header Column 3</th>
  <th>Header Column 4</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Row 2 - Item 1</td>
   <td>Row 2 - Item 2</td>
   <td rowspan="2"><b>Row 2:Nested table 1</b>
      <table border = "border">
         <tr><th>Row 1 Header</th><td>item</td></tr>
         <tr><th>Row 2 Header</th><td>item</td></tr>
         <tr><th>Row 2 Header</th><td>item</td></tr>
       </table>
       </td>
   <td>Row 2 - Item 4<br>A second line</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 3 - Item 1</td>
    <td>Row 3 - Item 2</td>

    <td rowspan="2">Row 3 - Item 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 4 - Item 1</td>
    <td>Row 4 - Item 2</td>
    <td>Row 4 - Item 3</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bottom td and add rowspan 2 to your nested table td tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border = "border">
 <tr>
  <th>Header Column 1</th>
  <th>Header Column 2</th>
  <th>Header Column 3</th>
  <th>Header Column 4</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Row 2 - Item 1</td>
   <td>Row 2 - Item 2</td>
   <td rowspan="2"><b>Row 2:Nested table 1</b>
      <table border = "border">
         <tr><th>Row 1 Header</th><td>item</td>
         <tr><th>Row 2 Header</th><td>item</td>
         <tr><th>Row 2 Header</th><td>item</td>
       </table>
       </td>
   <td>Row 2 - Item 4<br>A second line</td>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3 - Item 1</td>
    <td>Row 3 - Item 2</td>

    <td>Row 3 - Item 3</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 4 - Item 1</td>
    <td>Row 4 - Item 2</td>
    <td>Row 4 - Item 3</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rowspan` for combine two row and `colspan` for two column.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border = "border">
 <tr>
  <th>Header Column 1</th>
  <th>Header Column 2</th>
  <th>Header Column 3</th>
  <th>Header Column 4</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Row 2 - Item 1</td>
   <td>Row 2 - Item 2</td>
   <td rowspan="2"><b>Row 2:Nested table 1</b>
      <table border = "border">
         <tr><th>Row 1 Header</th><td>item</td>
         <tr><th>Row 2 Header</th><td>item</td>
         <tr><th>Row 2 Header</th><td>item</td>
       </table>
       </td>
   <td>Row 2 - Item 4<br>A second line</td>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3 - Item 1</td>
    <td>Row 3 - Item 2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Row 3 - Item 3</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 4 - Item 1</td>
    <td>Row 4 - Item 2</td>
    <td>Row 4 - Item 3</td>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**Result**

[Table format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POjHp.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border = "border">
    <tr>
        <th>Header Column 1</th>
        <th>Header Column 2</th>
        <th>Header Column 3</th>
        <th>Header Column 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 - Item 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 - Item 2</td>
        <td rowspan="2"><b>Row 2:Nested table 1</b>
            <table border = "border">
                <tr>
                    <th>Row 1 Header</th>
                    <td>item</td>
                <tr>
                    <th>Row 2 Header</th>
                    <td>item</td>
                <tr>
                    <th>Row 2 Header</th>
                    <td>item</td>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>Row 2 - Item 4<br>
            A second line</td>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3 - Item 1</td>
        <td>Row 3 - Item 2</td>
        <td>Row 3 - Item 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 4 - Item 1</td>
        <td>Row 4 - Item 2</td>
        <td>Row 4 - Item 3</td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```